# django: ForeignKeyField limit_choices_to "parents pk"?

Tags: django, django-models

I've a model (Parent model):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and another model (Child model):

```
class Addimg(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True)
    addimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

My Addimg Form:

```
class AddimgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Addimg 
        fields = ('post', 'addimg', 'width', 'height',)
```

views.py using the form:

```
def addimg(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddimgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            addimg = form.save(commit=False)
            addimg.addimg = request.FILES['addimg']
            addimg.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = AddimgForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

And my Problem is that when I create a "Child model" my post field returns all instances of allready created Post models as choices. What I want is that it automatic only displays the one Post it is related to without choices. Is ForeignKey the right model for that?

Any Ideas how this could work. thanks

Comment: That model does not make sense and I'm not sure what "addimg" is!  would it make more sense...``post = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True)`` ?

Comment: Why it does not make sense? addimg is the ForeignKey model and there can be more instances of Addimg class belong to the Post model atm should't that be possible?

Comment: its correct but I'll called it ``post = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True)`` meaning if you were to filter it would make more sense for example, ``Addimg.objects.filter(post=Post)`` which would return all "Addimgs" that have the same post i.e. Many-to-one relationships

Comment: y got it you are right I addimg was not a good name

Comment: Ok, so now you have changed it I am unsure what it is your asking what you have done is created a Many-to-one relationship which from the question is what you wanted

Comment: what is "Addimgs" out of curiosity?

Comment: When I Make a new Addimg Object with a form there is the post field(ForeignKey). And this field showing choices where i can decide to which Post my Addimg Object should be related to. But thats not what i want i want that it automatic set to the pk of his parent. like unique=True. Sorry for beeing so unclear

Comment: when you first created a new "Addimg" object it has no parent yet so you would need to pick one "Post" it would belong to. If you want if you pre-select the "Post" and not show a list it can be done. Without seeing your form its hard to say but you could either preselect i.e. ``AddimgForm(initial={'post': Post})`` or hide the ``post`` field and populate it yourself.

Comment: ok thanks for your patience. I'll check it out

Comment: Where do you use this `AddimgForm`? Inside the admin or inside a custom view? Please provide the code using the form.

Comment: custom view updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKey` field is translated into [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) inside a Django ModelForm. If you inspect that class you will notice that this type of field has an `queryset` attribute required. By default Django provides the full set of objects. You can override this inside your form `__init__` method by providing the `parent` object the form will need.

Consider the following example code:

```
def addimg(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddimgForm(request.POST, request.FILES, post=post)
        #...
    else:
        form = AddimgForm(post=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/edit.html', {'form': form})


class AddimgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Addimg 
        fields = ('post', 'addimg', 'width', 'height',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        post = kwargs.pop('post')
        super(AddimgForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['post'].queryset = Post.objects.filter(id=post.id)
```

Comment: ok this works great thank u very much! But still one little Problem left… Is there a way to change the default value of my form to post if?

Comment: Try with form [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) kwarg. `form = AddimgForm(post=post, initial={'post': post})`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a `Many-to-one relationship`. For example,

> post = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True)

This means you can filter on it for example,

```
Addimg.objects.filter(post=Post)
or
Post.objects.get(pk=1)
Post.addimg_set.filter(xyz=etc)
```

Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/